# Key not found in python dict while it's in dict.keys()

Tags: python, dictionary

What is the problem with this dict?
(debugging in the NetworkX AtlasView **getitem**)

```
>>> type(self._atlas)
<class 'dict'>
>>> type(key)
<class 'SyntaxToken'>
>>> self._atlas[key]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.3.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_exec2.py", line 3, in Exec
    exec(exp, global_vars, local_vars)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: при
>>> list(self._atlas.keys())[0] is key
True
>>> list(self._atlas.keys())[0] == key
True
>>> key in self._atlas
False
>>> key in set(self._atlas.keys())
True
>>> id(key), id(list(self._atlas.keys())[0])
(2487509812032, 2487509812032)
```

Comment: What is `type(key)`?

Comment: >>> type(key)
<class 'SyntaxToken'>

Comment: Sounds like it got mutated after it was added to the dict.

Comment: how could dict detect that, if at all?
>>> hash(key), hash(list(self._atlas.keys())[0])
(752442603772275336, 752442603772275336)

Comment: The dict *can't* detect that, which is why it's a problem.

Comment: The object values get mutated, not the key. Why the dict lookups are affected by that change? Apart from the other things, the snippet alone looks really odd. I can't understand

Comment: The results you've posted are all standard symptoms of mutating an object after you use it as a dict key. (Python objects that support `__hash__` are never supposed to be mutable in ways that change their hash, to avoid exactly this class of bug.) You don't think you've mutated the key, but you almost certainly have.